# Should I send the user ID of the user trying to authenticate in a HTTP header when using access token?

Tags: authentication, web-application, mysql, api

Im building a REST api for an ios application!

Would it be a good idea to send the user id (primary autoincrementing token in my mySQL database) of an account when authenticating with user token? (Happens on each get/post)

I thought it might significantly increase performance when checking for authencity of the token? What do you guys think? Does it reduce security? Is this common practice?

I am using HTTPS only of course.

Comment: An autoincrement token itself is a potential problem, as it's possible for an attacker to extract information from the knowledge IDs exist. For example, an attacker might be able to enumerate all users (if you ever expose data to a user via their ID) and can also find information like how many users are registered at any point or even how many users register in any timeframe. It's not *mandatory* to hide that information but it's usually a good idea.

Comment: @VLAZ Hhmm. Yeah I would have to store the user id inside the application. But thats what alot of apps do? Atleast many games have ”user id 192727” or similar mentioned in the settings! Many popular games! Why do they do that then? Dont they auto increment? I thought everyone used autoincrement. Anyway, would the performance boost be significant?

Comment: Some do it because they simply don't know better. Others know but don't care - exposing yourself to enumeration isn't necessarily bad. And others still may not even have sequential IDs but random ones, so "user id 192727” wouldn't be preceded by 192726 or followed by 192728. At any rate, as I said - it's a potential consideration. You may actually decide this is OK.

Comment: @vlaz But I dont even need to expose the id in any way not even to the app right? I can just use the accessToken for everything and the id never leaves my servers, right?

Comment: That's possible yes. Yet again, I'm just pointing out a potential issue. I don't know either your app nor your intention, so I can't say what exactly you need to do. It's up to you to decide.

Comment: @VLAZ Yeah that would work, but my app has social functions where you can add other users, and thats where you will need the id because you cant use other peoples accessTokens lmao. This is the biggest brainf*ck ive experienced. Or maybe im just tired.. The random IDs really seem like a good idea now.. But it will literally even take more storage.. But well, I have been doing security 1st untill now so why not use the random IDs as well. Yeah I really dont like the idea of knowing the amount of users etc. But my app's API does have app authentication. so that should not happen thought. :/

Comment: Why exactly do you think that sending up the user id will increase performance?

Comment: @ConorMancone Instead of the database looping over each user and checking their 256 char accesstoken to match the one sent, the db will go straight to the right column because of the autoincrementing id and check only once. Obviously it will increase performance.

Comment: @user109321948492842303 wouldn't you just create an index on the column where you store the accesstoken?  Then the database can find the correct record directly just as easily as it can find the user by their id.

Comment: Let me rephrase that: if you haven't created an index on your accesstoken column then that is your **real** problem, and sending up the user id is unnecessary.  I can expand that in more detail in an answer if you would like.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing the internal ID of a user with the user himself is not considered a bad practice, many apps do it. Relying on the secrecy of such an ID is, especially if it is autoincremented. This is called [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

> Would it be a good idea to send the user id (primary autoincrementing token in my mySQL database) of an account when authenticating with user token? (Happens on each get/post)

This can work, but be aware of the checks you need to make on the server side.

For **identification** and **authentication**

- Make sure the user ID exists in your app
- Make sure the token is valid
- Make sure the token belongs to the user id passed with the request

For **authorization**

- Make sure the user, who is now authentication, has access to the requested resource

> I thought it might significantly increase performance when checking for authencity of the token? What do you guys think? Does it reduce security? Is this common practice?

Depending on what authentication scheme you use, you may need to hit the DB anyway. The performance gain if any depends on your use-case. Generally, I would avoid premature optimization. Build the app, measure your bottleneck and if it ever looks like the authentication, authorization needs speeding up, that's when you start thinking.

For your use-case, I would probably go with JWT tokens, where you can encode the user id inside the token. This will take care of the identification and authentication part: as only you can issue such tokens, and the token content cannot be tampered with. Beware, JWT has some limitations [when dealing with session management](https://www.securitydrops.com/session-management/) and you still need to deal with authorization!

For alternative authentication methods take a look at the [Web Authentication Guide](https://www.securitydrops.com/the-web-api-authentication-guide/) I compiled a while ago.

Answer (score 1):

If you find yourself concerned about passing the ID to either GET or POST
a few changes to your design or approach may be needed.

- When creating a user account, generate a unique identifier (UUID) based either on ID or some other means like first-name, last-name. If the backend is python have a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html)
- Generate a slug based on first-name, or last-name eg. (firstname.lastname) or any other thing to generate a slug with.
- Encrypt the ID and decrypt it at the backend (quite expensive on memory)

This way you don't need to worry about [predictive eyes](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/218306/why-not-expose-a-primary-key).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by sending user ID "with user token".

If you mean "as a part of the token", then it is fine. On server you verify tokens and you will detect if token was modified, for instance if user has modified user ID (to access account of someone else).

If you mean "additionally to the token", then it is a bad idea. Because user can replace user ID with an ID of some other user and you will not be able to detect it. It means, every authenticated user will be able to work in the name of any other user: Access data he is not allowed to access, trigger some functions in the application that he is not allow to use.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answer to my comment, I think you have a much simpler solution.

Including the user id shouldn't impact performance at all, because you should have an index on your `AccessKey` column which allows your database to find your user in constant time.  In other words you're using a query like this:

```
SELECT id,email,password_hash FROM users WHERE access_key=?
```

And you're thinking about changing to something like this so that the primary index can be used:

```
SELECT id,email,password_hash FROM users WHERE id=? AND access_key=?
```

However, there is no difference between using the primary key or adding an index to a unique column.  At risk of overkill,I did a simple example using MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `api_token` char(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE `users_api_token` (`api_token`)
);
```

You can see that whether you query on the id or the api token, the query plans are exactly the same (the only difference is the choice of index to use):

```
mysql> describe select id from users where id=1;                
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users | NULL       | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

mysql> describe select id from users where api_token='asdf';
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type  | possible_keys   | key             | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users  | NULL       | const | users_api_token | users_api_token | 32      | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
```

But there is a big difference if you were to search on the first_name column which does not have an index:

```
mysql> describe select id from users where first_name='asdf';
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1547 |    10.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Now it is doing a full table scan, which you certainly want to avoid.  So if you don't have an index on your `AccessKey` column then you need to create an index there, or you need to also pass up the user id.  I'd personally just put an index on the `AccessKey` column, as it will be a much simpler and smaller change that reaches the same goal (better performance).

Comment: Just to play devil's advocate: the index for a varchar is going to be a lot larger than for an autoincrement integer, and the user id doesn't really need to be secret anyway. Of course it's unlikely it'll make any practical difference either way unless you have a _lot_ of users.

Comment: @AndrolGenhald Further nitpicking: an API token is being presumably generated with a fixed length, so a `VARCHAR` is the wrong choice anyway - something more like a `CHAR(32)` would be a better fit (although in a secure production system this table structure doesn't make sense regardless, since the user is assigned an API token when they login, and therefore may have more than one token at a time - one for each device).

Comment: Although regardless I would do the lookup by API Token rather than by id, since *conceptually* that is what you actually are doing.  After all you are literally authenticating an API token.  Therefore, I would to do the lookup by API Token and make the lookup-by-api-token as efficient as possible.  Also passing up the user id so that the query can be made more efficient seems like a lot of extra work and a deviation from the core goal here, which leaves more room for mistakes in the future.

Comment: @AndrolGenhald Ironically your comment is visible in the describe results.  The query on id has a `key_len=4`, while the query by `api_token` has `key_len=257`.  In practice though indeed, I doubt the difference will matter.  Now the difference in key length is smaller :p

Answer (score 0):

While it's OK, ideally you would include the userid in a claim of the jwt token.

That's easier said than done. If it's your own service that includes libraries for jwt and issues the tokens only for your own service, then you could add the claim.

If your system uses an external standalone Oidc system that's shared by multiple systems, you would need to login and add claims manually.

Having the claim in the jwt token means it's signed. So you don't need to do a database lookup. Apart from "federation" capabilities, I like that tokens result in fewer queries to the database.